# What's the effect of casting integer reference value to (const char*) and what's the difference between cast to char* and cast to const char* in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, constants, const-char

I'm reading some codes where sometimes casting integer reference value to const char * used with ostream is happened.

```
uint32_t val;// initialized by some value
void a(ostream& os) const{
     os.write((const char*)&val, sizeof(val));
}
```

1) What's the effect of casting integer reference type to (const char*)??

2) and is it same to use  (char *)&val as to use (const char *)??

2*) If not, what's the difference??

Comment: Let's break it down to simpler parts. 1. What's the difference between `const char*` and `char*`? 2. What does casting do? Pick one question (or both) and ask.

Comment: `&val` is pointer to integer; not integer reference.

Answer (score 1):

`char *` and `const char *` are different types. `char *` is a pointer to char and `const char *` is a pointer to a char which cannot be modified through the pointer.

In your example `(const char*)&val` will take the address of `val` and treat this as a pointer to char which data cannot be modified. It guarantees that the `write` function doesn't modify the data (but simply writes it to somewhere else). Passing `(char*)&val` as parameter does not guarantee this. `write` could then overwrite your `val`.

Comment: Thanks @Martin. but I recognize this is not what I wanna know. I've edited the title and clarified the questions more.